# Parse \n in json as a part of the string

Tags: c++, json, string, newline

I have to create a json string, using rapidjson..
My problem here is, my strings contains '\n' and the json can't be parsed because of this, I tested by removing all '\n' from the strings.. But it's not a solution because it ruins the encryption I have.

I have to sent the data to a webservice made in C# and the newlines should stay readable for the webservice.
Do anyone know if, I somehow can let these '\n' be a part of the string when parsing to json

```
// 1. Parse a JSON string into DOM.
string test = "{";
    test += "\"DatsId\":\"" + datsId + "\"";
    test += ",";
    test += "\"VsuId\":\"" + vsuId + "\"";
    test += ",";
    test += "\"EncryptedKeyString\":\"" + encryptedKey + "\"";
    test += ",";
    test += "\"EncryptedIVString\":\"" + encryptedIV + "\"";
    test += ",";
    test += "\"EncryptedString\":\"" + str_encrypted_base64 + "\"";
    test += ",";
    test += "\"SignedDataString\":\"" + signature2 + "\"";
    test += "}";
const char* json = test.c_str();
Document d;
d.Parse(test.c_str());

// 3. Stringify the DOM
StringBuffer buffer;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
d.Accept(writer);

// Output {"project":"rapidjson","stars":11}
std::cout << buffer.GetString() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Are the newlines in the variables?  I'm not seeing any newlines.

Comment: How do you escape the special chars in the variables `encryptedKey`, `encryptedIV`, ... ?

Comment: \n should be escape as \\n

Comment: All the encrypted string is encoded to base64 and there the \n is.. And is the reason why I cant parse

Comment: @RvdK I tried this, std::replace(encryptedIV.begin(), encryptedIV.end(), '\n', '\\n'); but it wont allow me and gives an error for the replace function

Comment: NathanOliver, encryptedKey and so on... is string variables, I can't copy/paste the whole string, to many characters

Comment: @KunoHeltborg When you encoded base64 contains \n you are not doing a base64 encoding. It should only be characters in 0123456789ABCDEF